# Get unique children in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's say I have photos in albums for events.

I want to run:

```
$photos = Photo::with('albums.events');
```

Later, I want to run:

```
foreach($events...)
```

On JUST the events that belonged to the photos that I found.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the relation between the two models :

```
class Photos extends Eloquent {

    public function events() { return $this->hasMany('events'); }

}
```

You can get the events like if it was normal relations, the eager loading changes nothing about that :

```
foreach (Photo::with('albums.events')->get as $photo) {
    foreach($photo->albums as $album) {
        $events = $album->events;
    }
}
```

If you want to simplify your code, you can declare a `hasManyThrough` relation :

```
class Photos extends Eloquent {

    public function albums() { return $this->hasMany('Album'); }
    public function events() { return $this->hasManyThrough('Event', 'Album');
}

foreach (Photo::with('albums.events')->get as $photo) {
    $events = $photo->events;
}
```

You should take few minutes and read [the official doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent), this is really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the relationships, I was hoping to not have to go outside of collections in order to achieve it. Looping through a list and building a new array isn't exactly eloquent.